# Generalizability study of subscaled rating instrument

Tags: factor-analysis, reliability, psychometrics, item-response-theory, validity

I have a school rating ($1$ thru $4$) instrument that consists of $9$ subscales (e.g., classroom instruction, school management etc.). Under each subscale, I have $6$ items on which rating occurs.

I have hired $6$ raters to each rate $5$ schools. That is, each rater will visit all schools and rate them independently.

My goal is to do a [**G** (Generalizability) study](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizability_theory) to establish the **reliability** of this rating instrument across all schools and all raters.

**Q:** Should I do separate G studies for each subscale?

Comment: Thanks for the link to G-theory. Unfortunately, it looks like it provides only a very brief overview, and the sources look a bit older. Hence, I think that this is not a very widely used theoretical framework. When you talk about establishing reliability across both schools and raters, I think that this **might** already be possible in a random effects framework. You'd have random intercepts for schools, and raters would be crossed (ie. they get their own non-nested random effects). If using sum scores, it seems like you'd just fit one model per subscale.

Comment: I suspect that not many readers here are familiar with G-theory. If true, the amount of help you get might be limited. Hopefully someone can prove me wrong, though. If not, consider if you can rephrase the question more generally (i.e. don't limit it to a lesser-known theory). If you can't, perhaps you'd try finding people familiar with this specific theory and consulting them.